# Running Total in HTML customer statement using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so i have one MySQL table with the transactions of customers expenses and deposits.
I am trying to incorporate a running total in a HTML table using PHP. The table gets the transactions by date, and displays all the correct data. However i am stuck on getting the running total.

The database has the following fields:

id, date, customer, description, total_running.

The total_running, does display a negative value for expenses and a positive value for deposits.

Here is the code where i try and calculate the running balance with the output:

```
<?php

// Get all the transactions
$getTransactions = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM statment_only WHERE customer LIKE '$value' AND date BETWEEN '$date1%' AND '$date2%' ");
// Get the starting balance
$getStartingBalance = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT total_running FROM statment_only WHERE id=1");

$startingBalance = $getStartingBalance->fetch_assoc();

// Iterate through all the transaction and calculate
$runningTotal = $startingBalance['total_running'];
while ($transaction = $getTransactions->fetch_assoc()) {
   $amount = $transaction['total_running'];
      if ($amount < 0) {
         $runningTotal = $amount - $runningTotal;
         echo $runningTotal;
         } else {
         $runningTotal = $amount + $runningTotal;
         echo $runningTotal;
         }
   }

?>
```

[Here is a picture of the Table with all the transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScTju.png)

The output displays like this, which is not correct.

0
980
15980

Is should respectively display in the table field as:

-980
0
15000

Comment: Why did you call that table column `total_running`? Shouldn't it be `amount`? **Tip:** Since you use a negative value for expenses and a positive value for deposits you can simply do: `$runningTotal += $amount;` without the `if ($amount < 0) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, the total_running holds the transaction values in the MySQL table, i did try the $runningTotal += $amount and it gives the following values: -1960 -980 14020

Comment: Also, why is the only condition in your query that gets the starting balance, `id=1` - when your query that fetches the amounts, explicitly limits this to certain customers (plural, or why LIKE?) and a date range ...?

Comment: _"the total_running holds the transaction values in the MySQL table"_ - and what are the actual _values_? You have only shown us part of that table, so I assume what we see in that screenshot, are the amounts.

Comment: You should try to actually understand what you're doing. The tip I gave you only solves one of the problems your code has. You have a problem with the starting balance as well. Then there's the possible problem of [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). But please deal with one problem at a time, and think about what your code actually does.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it right by doing the following with a while loop.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT total_running, @sum := @sum + total_running as total from statement_only join ( select @sum:=0 ) as transactions order by id");

while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $transaction = ($fetch['total']);
   ?>
  }
```

Then i would just echo the variable inside of my HTML table, and close the loop after the column in the table.